# Participants of the city meeting of young tourists or Participants of the young tourists city meeting?

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order

Which of the above sentences structure is correct? These are complete sentences, another title to a photograph. Do any of them sound English?

Comment: It depends a bit on what you mean. Both might work. The first has the sense that the city is having a meeting and specifically inviting young tourists. The second has the sense that the young tourists (who are in a given city) are having a meeting. Neither one is a sentence though, in the sense of having some sort of subject and some sort of action.

Comment: Thank you! Absolutely clear and very helpful. I understand that the sentences are grammatically incomplete, but could they be used  in this form as a title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The senses of both sentences are a bit different.

`Participants of the city meeting of young tourists` has the sense that the city is having a meeting and specifically inviting young tourists.

The "city to meeting" connection could be strengthened/emphasized: `Participants of the city's meeting of young tourists` if you want to do that.

`Participants of the young tourists city meeting` has the sense that the young tourists (who are in a given city) are having a meeting.

You might more emphasize that this meeting belongs to or is organized by the tourists: `Participants of the young tourists' city meeting` (adding the possessive).

Neither one is a sentence, in the sense of having some sort of subject and some sort of action.

Yes, they could be used in this form as a title - a bit wordy for a newspaper article though! (not that you are doing a newspaper article, but it does sound a bit like that).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm translating titles to a photographs from Russian, and Russian  is about 30% more wordy than English. So I'm a bit pressed by the original text. :)

Comment: _Participants in_ would be better.

Comment: @Kate Maybe it's more common too. Thank you.

Comment: @KateBunting is quite right. Participants in would be better.